# How to center content of width col_4 in HTML KickStart?

Tags: html, css, html5-kickstart

I have a form and I want it to be of width col_4 and in the center using HTML KickStart from 99lime.com. How do I do that? Currently I have this:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col_12">
        <form class="vertical" action="#">
            <input size="5" id="text_email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
            <input size=50 id="text_alias" type="text" name="alias" placeholder="Alias"><br>
            <input size=50 id="text_password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
            <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML Kickstart appears to use CSS floats to build the grid. To centre a box, you'd need to step outside of their grid system.

Perhaps add a custom class to the container div, e.g.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col_4 central">
        <form...
```

Then in your CSS, try this:

```
.grid .central {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Setting the `margin-left` & `margin-right` to `auto` will centre the div inside its parent (See http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html). It should pick up a width from the `col_4` class.